# What tables in Magento Database are Transactional emails save to?

Tags: database, magento

A while ago I had to start my Magento store over. Before that I created new transactional emails. I have my old database and I would like to find where these emails are located in the database so I don't have to recreate them.  What tables are they kept?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All custom transactional email template are stored in **core_email_template**.

Comment: Are the send mails saved in the database too?

Comment: @MCSell : Magento don't save any emails in db by default.

Comment: you say "any emails in db" are they stored anywhere else?

Comment: @MCSell Simple answer "NO"